# Partial Mocking Class with Multiple Static Methods with GMock

Tags: groovy, gmock, expandometaclass

I'm using GMock to add some unit testing to our existing Java projects.  We have multiple places where the methods needing to be tested are static methods, which utilize additional static methods within the method we want to test.

I would like to be able to partially mock the class, pretty much all static methods on the class other than the initial entry point for testing.

For example:

```
    class StaticClass {

      static void method(String one) {
          method2()
      }

      static void method(String one, String two) {
          ...
      }
    }
```

My hope is that I can mock the second static method but as soon as I do, method(String) goes MIA and executing the test fails with an expectation exception.  Is there a way I can partially mock the class, maintaining the functionality of the first method but mock the static access of the second method?

I've also tried using metaClass programming to mock the method, but if I set method equal to a closure, the first method goes MIA again.  Not sure how to do this with overloaded methods.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gmock, it mocks static methods and matches expectations according to their names. It means you cannot mock one overloaded method but not another.

It is the same with MOP of Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't involve GMock specifically, you could extend StaticClass inside your test file and override the methods there